# It does not return all values using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am working with an XML type database in PHP. Using SimpleXML I'm working with the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). But when collecting a value, it remains in the first node.

Here [XML-DataBase](http://milq.github.io/cs/1718/lmsgi/ut/06/course_catalog.xml)

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('course_catalog.xml');

foreach($xml->department->course as $paj) {
    if($paj->prerequisites->prereq == 'CS106B'){
        echo $paj->title . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

?>
```

> Output;
>
> Computer Organization and Systems
>
> Introduction to Probability for Computer Scientists

All belonging to the first department. But do not access the second department (where there is another -> prereq 'CS106B')

Then i tried this... to collect all the departments and not get stuck in the first (or so I think)

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('course_catalog.xml');

foreach($xml->department as $paj) {
    if($paj->course->prerequisites->prereq == 'CS106B'){
        echo $paj->course->title . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

?>
```

But it does not return anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only looping over the courses in the first department because of - `$xml->department->course`.  There are several points where there may be multiple elements, even with `prereq` may have multiple entries.

It may be simpler to use XPath to find the elements where `prereq` is 'CS106B'.  The following says - find the courses which have a `prerequisites` and then a `prereq` element with a value of `'CS106B'`...

```
$courses = $xml->xpath("//course[prerequisites/prereq/text()='CS106B']");
foreach ( $courses as $course ) {
    echo $course->title . PHP_EOL;
}
```

With your XML file, this produces

```
Computer Organization and Systems

Introduction to Probability for Computer Scientists

Digital Systems II
```

Without using XPath...

```
foreach($xml->department as $paj) {
    foreach ( $paj->course as $course ) {
        if ( isset($course->prerequisites)) {
            foreach ( $course->prerequisites->prereq as $prereq )   {
                if($prereq == 'CS106B'){
                    echo $course->title . PHP_EOL;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main thing is that not all courses seem to have prerequisites, so you have to check this before trying to loop over them.

Comment: ThankS!.. I had just managed to do it right now with Xpath. Is there any way to do it without Xpath? (sometimes I go crazy with Xpath)

Comment: I get it. I think I should start using Xpath. Although I do not find a good guide.
Thank so much for helping